# How can I rate player skills in a social deduction game?

Tags: scoring, the-resistance, rank, skill

I want to create a scoring system for my boardgame group that often plays the resistance (currently online over video call because its 2020).

In my short research I found that Elo score works for two player games and True skill applies to multiplayer games where everyone plays for themselves.

Resistance assassin mode with bodyguard, false commander and blind spy (Avalon expansion) seems far more difficult to score. So my thoughts were to use an Elo score with adjusted weights depending if you were vanilla or had a role.

The closest thing I got is [this online ranking reward system for werewolf](https://werewolf-online.fandom.com/wiki/Ranked_Mode). But that doesn't go into the math and score calculations.

I know this is a very niche question and more suited for Math Stack Exchange but any input or link would be much appreciated.

I will gladly post the math to this if I ever find a solution.

Comment: This might be quite a bit easier if you always play with the same group. Score ranking methods are useful for accounting for the skill of your opponent - a win against a low-ranking opponent doesn't count for as much as a win against a high-ranking opponent. But if you're always playing with the same group, you don't really have this issue - no one can pad their rank by playing against weaker players. A simple win rate over many games might suffice, as variations in roles should average out over time.

Comment: I wouldnt be surprised to see people better or worse depending which team they are on. It might make sense to have a separate spy/resistance rating. I think special roles would average out though.